# ERROR registering goldengate process OGG-08221

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

This error is thrown while registering a process in Oracle Goldengate.

> ERROR   OGG-08221  Cannot register or unregister EXTRACT XYZ because of the following SQL error: OCI Error ORA (status = 26664-ORA-26664: cannot create GoldenGate process OGG$XYZ

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should just *wait*.

> **Error code: ORA-26664**
>
> **Description**: cannot create string process string
>
> **Cause**: An attempt was made to create a GoldenGate, XStream or Streams process when another was being created concurrently.
>
> **Action**: Wait for the creation of the other GoldenGate, XStream or Streams process to finish before attempting to create the process.